# Trying to increase a high score by user input in python

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a homework assignment for my game dev. class and I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to add numbers to a high score that has already been hardwired in by the use of user input. For example; Trying to add 100 points to Roger who currently has 3456 points. I just haven't quite figured out what I'm doing wrong to get the code to work. All and any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

```
str1 = ["Roger", 3456]
str2 = ["Justin", 2320]
str3 = ["Beth", 1422]
enter = 0
start = 0
Roger = ()
def incdec(sco):
    return addit

def addition(num1):
    return num1 + num1

def square(num):
    print("I'm in square")
    return num * num

def display(message):
    """Display game instuctions"""
    print(message)

def instructions():
    """Display game instuctions"""
    print("Welcome to the world's greatest game")


def main():
    instructions()
    scores = [str1, str2, str3]

    start = input("Would you like to view the high score options? y/n ")
    if start == "y":
        print("""\
        Hello! Welcome to the high scores!
        Here are the current high score leaders!:
        """)
        print(scores)
        print("""\n\
        0 - Sort high scores
        1 - Add high score
        2 - Reverse the order
        3 - Remove a score
        4 - Square a number
        5 - Add 2 numbers together
        6 - Add to a score
        7 - Subtract from a score
        """)
        option = int(input("Please enter your selection "))
        while option < 8:
            print(scores)
            if option == 0:
                scores.sort()
                print("These are the scores sorted alphabetically")
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 1:
                print(scores)
                print("Please enter your name and score; After entering your name, hit the return key and enter your score")
                name = input()
                score = int(input())
                entry = (name,score)
                scores.append(entry)
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 2:
                print(scores)
                scores.reverse()
                print("\nHere are the scores reversed")
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 3:
                print(scores)
                print("Please enter the high score you would like to remove. After typing the name, hit the return key and enter the score")
                name1 = input()
                score1 = int(input())
                remove = (name1,score1)
                scores.remove(remove)
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 4:
                val = int(input("Give me a number to square"))
                sqd = square(val)
                print(sqd)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 5:
                val0 = int(input("Give me one number"))
                val1 = int(input("Give me another number"))
                addi = (val0 + val1)
                print(addi)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 6:
                sc0 = input("Please enter the person whose score you would like to add to ")
                sc1 = int(input("Please enter the amount you would like to add to their score "))
                addit =(sc0 + str(sc1))
                print(addit)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 7:
                break

main()
```

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what is not working? Maybe some sample input and output?

Comment: Option 6. Say I want to add 100 points to Roger's current 3456. With how the code is currently set up, it only prints back out 'Roger', 100 @JoshuaGilman

Comment: I would probably start with actually using the variable `scores`, for one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a number to a string. What you need to do is search for the player in your `scores` list and then add the given number to their current score. Using your current structure, you could do the following:

```
def update_score(scores, person, amount):
    # Loop through the current scores
    for score in scores:
        # Find the person we're looking for
        if score[0].lower() == person.lower():
            # Update their score
            score[1] += amount

    return scores
```

And then modify as such:

```
...
            elif option == 6:
                sc0 = input("Please enter the person whose score you would like to add to ")
                sc1 = int(input("Please enter the amount you would like to add to their score "))

                scores = update_score(scores, sc0, sc1)
                print(scores)

                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
...
```

Which produced for me:

```
Please enter the person whose score you would like to add to roger
Please enter the amount you would like to add to their score 100
[['Roger', 3556], ['Justin', 2320], ['Beth', 1422]]
```

However, I would refactor a lot of the boilerplate away and use dictionary lookups for tracking players. But the above solution solves your stated problem.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank you for your help!